# Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have tried Mongo geospatial Query in PHP.. I have faced Following Error i have wrote 2 PHP script.. in my **GeoPHP** create Object From Class and Call the Member Method And my another PHP script **class.master.php** wrote a class and Member Methods

GeoPHP.php

```
<?php
require 'class.master.php';
$lat = 27.53864605; 
$long =  94.57980515; 
$distance = 5;

$geObj = new Geo;

$geObj->DbInst('dbname', 'collectionname');

$geObj->assignGeo($lat, $long, $distance);

$resultFld = array('id', 'name', 'stid', 'dis_id', 'ta_id');

$query = array('location'=>
                    array("\$near"=>
                            array("\$geometry"=>
                                array('type'=>'Point', 'coordinates'=>
                                    array($long, $lat)),"\$minDistance"=> 0, "\$maxDistance"=>$distance
                            )
                    )
        ); 

$result = $geObj->getResult($query, $resultFld);

?>
```

class.master.php

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

class Geo{

    private $latitude, $longitude, $distance;
    private $uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    private $databaseName;
    private $db;

    public $collection;

    public function DbInst($dbname, $collName){
        // Mongo Connection Establish
        $con = new MongoDB\Client($this->uri);
        $this->databaseName = $dbname;
        $this->db = $con->selectDatabase($this->databaseName);

        $this->collection = $collName;
    }

    public function assignGeo($lat, $long, $dis){
        $this->latitude = $lat;
        $this->longitude = $long;
        $this->distance = $dis;
    }

    public function getResult($query, &$resFld){

        $cursor = $this->collection->find($query);

        return $cursor; 

    }
}
?>
```

above Script return following Error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
>   D:\xampp_1.8.3\htdocs\GeoMongo\class.master.php on line 35

how to fix this error?

Comment: $this->collection is not an object, dump it and check what it contains.

Comment: $this->collection is class variable and it contains 'collection Name' @Maytyn

Comment: In DbInst function you assign string to collection property. In function getResult() you want to call function find() from collection property which is a string.

Comment: ya Got it Thank U Maytyn

Answer (score 0):

Set your collection as:

```
$this->collection = $this->db->selectCollection($collName);
```